# How to handle changing the size of the terminal window?

Tags: c++, linux, ncurses

I'm creating a project that uses the ncurses library. However, I have a huge problem with handling the event associated with changing the size of the terminal window. Currently, when the window is smaller than what I would like to display, the part that does not fit is cut off. So far, I have only been able to find information to use `newpad` / `subpad` in such situations. The problem is that by reading the documentation, I do not understand how to use it. I do not know if I should use a `pad` instead of a `window`, or create a `window` in a `pad`? I would like to ask for sources that describe more accurately the use of the `pads`. Alternatively, if I should use something different then `pads`, I am asking for a hint what should be used in the project.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: ncurses has [test/sample/demo](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) programs which include pads.

Comment: @ThomasDickey thank you very much. It is exactly what I needed.